# How to update a Smartsheet with JSON data using Python?

Tags: python, json, http, smartsheet-api

I'm using the smartsheet-python-sdk and I have a simple JSON file that I want to update my Smartsheet sheet with.

I have succeeded in pulling sheet data down using the python requests library but I'm wondering how exactly I would post data.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
baseUrl = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets"

req = requests.get(baseUrl, verify=False, headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer %s" %accessToken})
print(req.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest checking out our API documentation, specifically the [Python code samples](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#python-sample-code) section which provides a little more information. In addition, we provide code samples for almost all of our operations in the API documentation. Simply select Python when browsing the API docs.

In reference to posting data, that would depend on which operation you'd like to use. Here's an example of a "[Create Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#create-sheet-in-%22sheets%22-folder)" operation:

```
# Create sheet in "Sheets" folder.
sheet = smartsheet.models.Sheet({
    'name': 'newsheet',
    'columns': [{
            'title': 'Favorite',
            'type': 'CHECKBOX',
            'symbol': 'STAR'
        }, {
            'title': 'Primary Column',
            'primary': True,
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER'
        }, {
            'title': 'Status',
            'type': 'PICKLIST',
            'options': [
                'Not Started',
                'Started',
                'Completed'
            ]
        }
    ]
})
action = smartsheet.Home.create_sheet(sheet)
sheet = action.result
```

You can find similar examples for other operations. If you have additional questions, you can always reach out to our API support team: api@smartsheet.com